# youtubeplayer no angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Olá, eu estou tentando implementar um player do youtube usando angular 4, mas só estou conseguindo cria-lo usando código javascript. Segue o código:

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');

      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      var player;
      setTimeout( 
        function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
          player = new YT.Player('player', {
            height: '360',
            width: '640',
            videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
      },3000);
```

e no componente.ts da pagina que quero que o player execute eu importo o codigo:

```
import '../../apiyoutube.js';
```

o problema é que quero usar varios eventos que quero recuperar do banco de dados e etc, então queria manipular os atributos deste codigo em services e no componente que usam typescript. Como que consigo acessar atributos deste codigo isoladamente? eu já tentei ate desistir mas... tem como criar esse player usando typescript?

obs: coloquei um setTimeOut porque desta forma que importei o angular primeiro executa o código .js e depois renderiza o html, e o código não conseguia acessar o id na pagina html